# Running a C compiler on Windows Subsystem for LInux

Tags: compile

I want to use the compile-to-C functionality of Mathematica. Has anyone gotten the C compiler driver to recognize a C compiler (for instance gcc) installed on a Windows Subsystem for Linux?

I am running: Windows 10 and Version 1809

Mathematica 12

Comment: "I want to use the compile to C functionality" Can you be more specific about what exactly you want to do? The statement is ambiguous. If you want `Compile` with `"CompilationTarget" -> "C"`, then the simple answer is that this is not possible with the WSL compiler because it produces shared libraries for Linux which cannot be loaded into a Windows process.